# CakePHP paginator ignoring order, but only for certain values

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, mongodb-query

When paginating my user model in CakePHP, I can sort by some values, but not others. I can order the results by *created* or *email* fine, for example, but ordering by *username* or *reputation* comes back with a list of users in a seemingly arbitrary order. So for instance:

`$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('User.is_active' => true), 'limit' => 24, 'order' => array('User.created' => 'DESC'));`

works as expected, but

`$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('User.is_active' => true), 'limit' => 24, 'order' => array('User.reputation' => 'DESC'));`

doesn't.

I thought at first this might be a database issue, but when I search the database directly everything is returned and sorted as expected.

**Note:** I'm using MongoDB with ichikaway's MongoDB plugin for CakePHP; paginating users used to work fine, so I'm positive it's not a bug with the plugin, but something has changed somewhere and I can't pinpoint what.

Finally, when I view the queries in the debug info, I can see that CakePHP isn't even passing the *order* value to the database when searching. The first search above displays this:

`db.users.find( {"is_active":true}, [] ).sort( {"created":-1} ).limit( 24 ).skip( 0 )`

and the second this:

`db.users.find( {"is_active":true}, [] ).sort( [] ).limit( 24 ).skip( 0 )`

Why is CakePHP letting me order by some things, but not others?

Comment: Based on the description, it seems like there must be some difference between the `User.created` and `User.reputation` fields in your model class.  Are they different types (eg `datetime` vs `string`)?

Comment: They are indeed, but I've actually just determined that the problem was caused by a single document without the fields in question. Seems strange to me that this would blow up pagination but work fine for regular searches, but I'm no Cake expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. It *was* a database error; somehow, a record got created with only a few of the fields in it (e.g., _*id, created, modified,* and a few others), which not coincidentally were the only ones that I could sort by. Deleting it got everything back to normal.

Strange that doing a search would work fine, but paginating with the same parameters wouldn't. Maybe it is a plugin/Cake bug after all?